# What inputs would cause this function to not terminate?

Tags: scheme, lisp, stack-overflow, termination

I am trying to prove this function in ACL2s/Lisp, but it is returning a stack overflow error, though I can't see the flaw in the code.

```
(defunc foo (x y)
 :input-contract (and (natp x) (natp y))
 :output-contract (natp (foo x y))
 (cond ((equal 0 x) (+ y 1))
       ((equal 0 y) (foo (- x 1) 1))
       (t (foo (- x 1) (foo x (+ y 1))))))
```

Comment: What values are you passing in for a stack overflow?

Comment: I am not. ACL2s has an automatic theorem prover that does pass inputs into it but I can't see what they are, but one of them is causing a stack overflow so it rejects the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't any positive `x` and `y` cause this to overflow? Let's look at `(foo 1 1)`.

Neither `x` nor `y` is zero, so it gets to the `t` branch of the cond, and calls:

```
(foo 0
     (foo 1 2))
```

Ok, let's evaluate the inner `foo` call:

```
(foo 1 2)
```

Similarly, it gets to the `t` branch of the cond, and calls:

```
(foo 0
     (foo 1 3))
```

Let's evaluate the inner `foo`:

```
(foo 1 3)
```

You can see where this is going. The `t` branch calls:

```
(foo 0
     (foo 1 4))
```

And so forth. This will happen anytime both `x` and `y` are nonzero. Where did you get this code? What are you trying to do with it? Running it's also a good idea to see what overflows. In this case, you would get stack overflows with nearly every possible call.